# Julia equivalent to R's replace()

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

In R, there is a `replace(A, I, B)` function that replaces the values in *A* with indices given in *I* by those given in *B* (*B* can be a scalar). What is the easiest way to do this in Julia?

Comment: If you look on the source of `replace` its only `x[list] <- values`. So maybe `A[I] = B` ?

Comment: Yes, it does that basic thing but is useful to change a variable inside a function like `f(replace())`.

Comment: I added  an answer below that addresses your question by simply making a new function- it doesn't seem that there is function like you are looking for built in.

Comment: So you want something like `replace` in `R` what is *not* updating the original vector but is making a *copy* of it, updating and returning the modified copy?

Comment: Yes, the setindex() function provided in the below answer by @ahnlabb works, but not for scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` in `R` is not updating the original and returning the updated vector so that it could be used inside a function and `R` is automatically repeating (broadcasting) values if there is a need that they fit.
Maybe the following function is doing what you need.

```
function Rreplace!(A, I, B)
  A[I] .= B
  A
end

A = [1,2,3,4,5]; I = [1,3]; B = [7, 8];

Rreplace!(copy(A), I, B)
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
# 7
# 2
# 8
# 4
# 5

Rreplace!(copy(A), I, 9)  # Works with scalar
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
# 9
# 2
# 9
# 4
# 5

identity(Rreplace!(copy(A), I, 9))  # Works in a function
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
# 9
# 2
# 9
# 4
# 5

A  # A is not changed
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5

Rreplace!(A, I, 9);  # if there is a need A can be changed
A
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
# 9
# 2
# 9
# 4
# 5
```

As in `R` vectors will be repeated until they match the length this will also work in `R`.

```
## R ##
replace(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(1,3,4,5), c(7,8))
#[1] 7 2 8 7 8
```

But this will *not* work with the provided function.

```
Rreplace!([1,2,3,4,5], [1,3,4,5], [7,8])
#ERROR: DimensionMismatch: array could not be broadcast to match destination
```

And in `R` negative indices select to opposite.

```
## R ##
replace(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(-2,-4), 9)
#[1] 9 2 9 4 9
```

But this will also *not* work with the provided function.

```
Rreplace!([1,2,3,4,5], [-2,-4], 9)
#ERROR: BoundsError:
```

So maybe the function should look like the following to be *equivalent to `R`'s `replace`*:

```
function Rreplace!(A, I, B::Array)
  all(I .< 0) && (I = setdiff(eachindex(A), -I))
  A[I] = repeat(B, length(I) ÷ length(B))
  A
end

function Rreplace!(A, I, B::Number)
  all(I .< 0) && (I = setdiff(eachindex(A), -I))
  A[I] .= B
  A
end

Rreplace!([1,2,3,4,5], [1,3,4,5], [7,8])
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
# 7
# 2
# 8
# 7
# 8

Rreplace!([1,2,3,4,5], [-2,-4], 9)
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
# 9
# 2
# 9
# 4
# 9
```

Answer (score 3):

The corresponding function in Julia is [`setindex!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.setindex!-Tuple%7BAbstractArray,%20Any,%20Vararg%7BAny%7D%7D):

> `setindex!(A, X, inds...)`
>
> Store values from array X within some subset of A as specified by inds. The syntax `A[inds...] = X` is equivalent to
> `(setindex!(A, X, inds...); X)`.

Example in the REPL:

```
julia> A = [1,2,3,4,5]; I = [1,3]; B = [100, 101];

julia> setindex!(A, B, I);

julia> A
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 100
   2
 101
   4
   5
```

Note that `setindex!` mutates the argument. We can use `copy` to allocate a new array.

```
julia> setindex(A, X, inds...) = setindex!(copy(A), X, inds...)
setindex (generic function with 1 method)

julia> A = [1,2,3,4,5]; B = [100, 101]; I = [1,3];

julia> setindex(A, B, I)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 100
   2
 101
   4
   5

julia> A
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It fails when `B` is scalar, as asked by the OP. Imo, it is also un-idiomatic. The correct and idiomatic answer is `A[I] .= B`

Comment: Definitely agree it's not idiomatic. I've seldom used/seen setindex! except for operator overloading. I interpret OP's question & comment as asking about a *function* in the standard library that is a close analog to `replace`. Both broadcasted assign and setindex! fail to correspond perfectly since R's `replace` isn't mutating but broadcasted assign returns the materialized array instead of the updated LHS array. `A[I] .= B` currently parses to: `broadcast!(identity, Broadcast.dotview(A, I), B)` so doesn't correspond to a function in Base. I'll expand the answer & refer to yours as the idiom.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is straightforward:

`A[I] .= B`

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this normally would be with assigning by index:

```
array = [0,2,3]
array[1] = 1

# array is now [1,2,3]
```

Above, you mentioned the need for a function, and also the capability to change multiple indices.

This isn't a function in Base, but it's relatively painful to make it yourself.

```
# Make a base function. Error catching is optional but included here.

function replace!(ar::Vector,i::Int,val)
    i<0&&error("Index must be non-negative")
    i>size(ar)[1]&&error("Index out of range")
    ar[i]=val
end

# Extend function for use on vector inputs

function replace!(ar::Vector,i::Vector{Int},val::Vector)
    size(i)!=size(val)&&error("Must have same number of indices and values")
    for j in 1:size(i)[1]
        replace!(ar,i[j],val[j])
    end
end

# Example Below

myArray = [9,9,9,9,9]

replace!(myArray,1,5)
# MyArray is now [5, 9, 9, 9, 9]

replace!(myArray,[2,3,4],[6,7,8])
# MyArray is now [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This is using Julia's multiple dispatch feature, where a function can be defined differently for different input parameters. It is a core feature, and one which makes code very understandable.

Keep in mind that if you know what kind of data the input array will contain, you could modify this to extend the array if you input an index that is too high by filling it ith some filler value, but it wasn't asked for so it wasn't included.